# Python ThreadingMixin and BaseHTTPServer

Tags: python, multithreading, web-services, webserver, threadpool

I am trying to evaluate various languages to build a small-in-size high-throughput application server. It needs to do small stuff like getting a request, reading data from a separate server running cache application (memcached, redis) , and sending back a 5 - 10 line XML or JSON. Very high throughput ~ 1000 per sec in production atleast. I have this on Nginx - PHP and memcached takes 5+ ms to send back all the required data so there is some network IO which blocks.

I was looking at Python's BaseHTTPServer class. I am not a python guru, but i need to know how it works behind the scene. If you read this page -

http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html

It says "To build asynchronous handlers, use the ThreadingMixIn and ForkingMixIn classes."

Is it really Asynchronous or does it start One Thread Per Client. If it is on one thread per client model - are these OS level threads ? If i stick to one thread per client model, will Python's GC clear stuff fast enough if i give it high RAM, 8 core amazon instance.

Answer (score 6):

[ForkingMixIn](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/SocketServer.py#l495) as you can see in the source code, does a real fork. [ThreadingMixIn](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/SocketServer.py#l568) uses the Python threads. So you have to deal with the GIL, which means even if it's using the underlying os-threading mechanism, there will be no concurrent processing of your python-threads. I wouldn't recommend it for a high-throughput server.

So in short: **NO**, they are not asynchronous per your definition. If you want "real" asynchronous (one core/process/thread) functionality you should look into: [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) or [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/overview.html) or maybe [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/). The later probably wouldn't meet your definition of asynchronous either.

I would suggest to use torndado with nginx. There is a post [in google groups](http://groups.google.com/group/python-tornado/browse_thread/thread/18afe7d87f4d2616) about how to set it up. Because the internal Tornado-Server doesn't have all standards implemented, you could use a "real" server as proxy.

Comment: Great. Did some research. Which technology would you use if you were in such a situation ? I need to port that Nginx PHP to something else. Some persistent application which has a HTTP server built in.

Comment: Tornado in a standalone Py application or with Nginx ? This benchmark shows that Nginx + Tornado did 8000+ per sec. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tornado_%28web_server%29

Comment: @Don Question : ThreadingMixin is using threading.thread which is AFAIK an os level thread in which case it is not dealing with the GIL. Which would make threadingmixin an ideal choice for the OP.

Comment: @RaghuramOntiSrinivasan: Despite the use of a real os-thread, CPython still creates a GIL, to avoid any possible nasty surprises. If you want GIL-less threads, you would have to wirte a C-Extension and manually disable the GIL.

Comment: @RaghuramOntiSrinivasan: In fact it is explicitly stated in the "threading" documentation, that the CPython version uses the GIL! https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html So your assumptions are wrong. I wish you were right!

Comment: interesting. i missed that! thanks for pointing it out @DonQuestion! unfortunately, i cant change the downvote since its locked. anyway i can get around that?

Comment: @RaghuramOntiSrinivasan Yes, editing the answer removes the "Global Vote Lock" ;-).